# Return on latest timestamped value from a database

Tags: sql-server

I'm pretty new to SQL so please bear with me!!

I have a table - `MeterData` - that looks like this:

(I will also note that the actual database has 160+ meterIDs, 23 quantities against each meterID and 1.5million+ records, and growing every day!)

```
MeterID TimeStamp          Value Quantity
------------------------------------------
meter1  09/10/2017 07:00:00 2.3 Power
meter1  09/10/2017 07:15:00 2.4 Power 
meter1  09/10/2017 07:30:00 2.7 Power
meter1  09/10/2017 07:00:00 230 Voltage
meter1  09/10/2017 07:15:00 229 Voltage
meter1  09/10/2017 07:30:00 230 Voltage
meter1  09/10/2017 07:00:00 978 Energy
meter1  09/10/2017 07:15:00 979 Energy
meter1  09/10/2017 07:30:00 980 Energy
meter2  09/10/2017 07:00:00 15.8    Power 
meter2  09/10/2017 07:15:00 14.7    Power 
meter2  09/10/2017 07:30:00 18.9    Power 
meter2  09/10/2017 07:00:00 415 Voltage
meter2  09/10/2017 07:15:00 414 Voltage
meter2  09/10/2017 07:30:00 414 Voltage
meter2  09/10/2017 07:00:00 15687   Energy
meter2  09/10/2017 07:15:00 15688   Energy
meter2  09/10/2017 07:30:00 15689   Energy
```

I want to query the database to return multiple "Value" with the latest timestamp but for specific "Quantity" and "MeterID", e.g. the result I am trying to achieve should look like this:

```
Value   MeterID   Timestamp              Quantity
--------------------------------------------------
 2.7    meter1    09/10/2017 07:30:00    Power
18.9    meter2    09/10/2017 07:30:00    Power
```

If I query the database with this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    Value, MeterID, Timestamp, Quantity
FROM 
    MeterData
WHERE 
    MeterID = 'meter1' AND Quantity = 'Power'
ORDER BY 
    Timestamp DESC
```

I get the desired result but for only ONE "MeterID":

```
Value   MeterID   Timestamp             Quantity
------------------------------------------------
 2.7    meter1    09/10/2017 07:30:00   Power
```

But how do I get a result for multiple MeterIDs? Obviously, an `UNION` clause doesn't work because I have an `ORDER BY` clause... I have tried `LAST_VALUE` and `INNER JOIN`

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use of a Common Table Expression with ROW_NUmber should work
Edited with test data from question above

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MeterData(
     MeterId NVARCHAR(20)
    ,TimeStamp  DATETIME
    ,Value      DECIMAL(10,2)
    ,Quantity   NVARCHAR(20)

)
INSERT INTO dbo.MeterData
( MeterId , TimeStamp , Value , Quantity)
VALUES
('meter1',  '09/10/2017 07:00:00', 2.3 ,'Power' ),
('meter1',  '09/10/2017 07:15:00', 2.4 ,'Power' ) ,
('meter1',  '09/10/2017 07:30:00', 2.7 ,'Power' ),
('meter1',  '09/10/2017 07:00:00',230 ,'Voltage'),
('meter1',  '09/10/2017 07:15:00',229 ,'Voltage'),
('meter1',  '09/10/2017 07:30:00',230 ,'Voltage'),
('meter1',  '09/10/2017 07:00:00',978, 'Energy'),
('meter1',  '09/10/2017 07:15:00',979, 'Energy'),
('meter1',  '09/10/2017 07:30:00',980, 'Energy'),
('meter2',  '09/10/2017 07:00:00',15.8 ,'Power' ) ,
('meter2',  '09/10/2017 07:15:00',14.7 ,'Power' ) ,
('meter2',  '09/10/2017 07:30:00',18.9 ,'Power' ) ,
('meter2',  '09/10/2017 07:00:00',415 ,'Voltage'),
('meter2',  '09/10/2017 07:15:00',414 ,'Voltage'),
('meter2',  '09/10/2017 07:30:00',414 ,'Voltage'),
('meter2',  '09/10/2017 07:00:00',15687, 'Energy'),
('meter2',  '09/10/2017 07:15:00',15688, 'Energy'),
('meter2',  '09/10/2017 07:30:00',15689, 'Energy')


;WITH cte
AS(
    SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY MeterId, Quantity
                                    ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC)
    FROM dbo.MeterData
)
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but ROW_NUMBER won't work as the row for the latest TimeStamp of any given MeterID will change every 15 minutes. The DB grows by +\- 1500 rows per day.

Comment: I don't understand why ROW_NUMBER will not work. If the latest timestamp changes as will the query by selecting the most recent timestamp for each Meterid, Value, Quantity combination.

Comment: @LukStorms I'm not worried about table growth the OP is. But yes, your suggestion can alleviate his concerns

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze oops, copied wrong name... sorry. But are you sure the `Value` should also be in the `PARTITION BY` ?

Comment: @EnergyAuto If you're worried about the table growth, you could add a condition in the CTE to limit it to the timestamps of the last X days. F.e. `WHERE CONVERT(date, [Timestamp]) >= CONVERT(date, GetDate()-7)`

Comment: @LukStorms Yes, you're right, Removed "Value" from Partition By